# How can I add a Count with a condition from another table to a column/equation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a table that calculates some player stats

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total Games',
        COUNT(case Position when 1 then 1 else null end) as 'Wins',
        CAST(CAST(COUNT(case Position when 1 then 1 else null end) as decimal(10,2)) / cast(Count(*) as decimal(10,2)) as decimal(10,2)) as 'Win %',        
        COUNT(case when Position IN(1,2) then 1 else null end) as 'Total HU',
        CAST(CAST(COUNT(case Position when 1 then 1 else null end) as decimal) / CAST(COUNT(case when Position IN(1,2) then 1 else null end) as decimal) as decimal(10,2)) as 'Win HU %',
        COUNT(case when Position IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) then 1 else null end) as 'Final Tables',
        CAST(CAST(COUNT(case Position when 1 then 1 else null end) as decimal) / CAST(COUNT(case when Position IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) then 1 else null end) as decimal) as decimal(10,2)) as 'Win % Final Tables' 
FROM EventResults
WHERE PlayerID = 1
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNQmg.png)

I am looking to also add the stat "Overall average % of field beaten", but I am not sure how.
The relevant columns in "EventResults" table are 'EventID', 'PlayerID' and 'Position'

[Image of EventResult table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cygr.png)

The equation would be

```
(AVG( (Position of PlayerID with EventID) / (Count of that EventID) ) / -1 ) * -1
```

But I can't wrap my head around how to get that into a column.

Comment: Your problem is that up until this, you’ve been able to use aggregate functions. In this case you need to calculate each row individually before taking the average. You may want to calculate this separately then join it back in. You’ll need to use analytical functions to get the counts for each event against the position.

Comment: Also, on a slightly unrelated note, some final tables have more than 8 participants...just look at the WSOP.

Comment: Thanks, gotta take a dive into analytical functions. Sounds fun!

Also this is for a local league and unfortunately I don't think there is table in the DB containing if event final table is 6/8/9 leaving me to hard coding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to use analytical function to figure this out correctly.  This query should calculate the average percent of field beaten for each player:

```sql
SELECT sub.playerid, AVG(sub.r_field_beaten) * 100 AS PCT_FIELD_BEATEN
FROM (SELECT er.playerid, 
             er.eventid, 
             (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY er.eventid)-er.position+1) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY er.eventid) AS R_FIELD_BEATEN
      FROM EventResults er) sub
GROUP BY sub.playerid;
```

As you may have noticed, I changed your formula a bit.  I took the total number of participants subtracted by the position plus 1 (The plus 1 is to take the player out of the field) and divided it by the total number of participants.  Lets say you win a tournament of 100 people the formula would be (100-1+1)/100 resulting in 1.  Thus you beat 100% of the field.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I need to look into analytical functions and try wrap my head around them a bit.

I am still having a bit of trouble with your code though,  all the "PCT_FIELD_BEATEN" fields returned 0, so I threw a cast to make it a double and I don't think its return the right results.

[img](https://i.imgur.com/OIdClkJ.png)
As you can see, PlayerID 2 has a position of 2 in event 1 but it returns 0, I am sure I'm missing something sorry!

Comment: EDIT, yeah was me being dumb. Needed to cast them to decimal before there are divided. Looks more reasonable now!
[link](https://i.imgur.com/bZiZokf.png)